# How do you decide whether to use "vous" or "tu"? / Comment choisir entre « vous » et « tu » ?

Tags: usage, choix-de-mot, politesse, vouvoiement

When talking to someone, how do you decide when to use "vous" or "tu"?

Example:

> Comment allez-vous ?

*or*

> Comment vas-tu ?

---

Comment choisir entre *vous* et *tu* quand on s'adresse à quelqu'un ?

Comment: Perhaps the most difficult point in French day-to-day interactions for English-only native speakers.

Comment: @Evpok and even for native speakers ;)

Comment: You might be interested in [this](http://meta.french.stackexchange.com/questions/37/est-ce-quon-se-tutoie) related question on meta.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

This is one of the most subtle and complicated points in the French language. In fact, I think you could say that it has more to do with the culture than with the language itself. It's not really something that can be easily taught on this site.

Until you have a good feel for it, you can use the following rules of thumb:

- If you are young (say, 24 and younger), use *tu* with anyone your age and younger, unless the situation is very impersonal (e.g. with a cashier in a shop).
- If you are older than this, use *tu* with young children (in any situation) and with adolescents and young adults in social situations.
- Use *tu* on the Internet unless you're trying to be very formal, or you're talking with someone whom you know offline and address as *vous*.
- If you are in school or university, use *vous* with your teachers, no matter their age.
- If someone who is your **social equal** (co-worker with the same job, for example) uses *tu*, you can safely use *tu* as well. This may not apply to social **superiors** (but that's open for debate: see Sylvain's answer! In any case, it's far less clear-cut.)
- In all other situations, use *vous* unless the person you're talking to specifically asks you to use *tu*.
- (May seem obvious, but needs to be included): Always use *vous* when addressing more than one person. This is a grammatical rule and you will not be understood if you use *tu*.

Again, these rules are very approximate and everyone will have a different opinion on this, but they should keep you from shocking anyone too badly until you develop your own style. Also remember that these are based on my experience in France; different Francophone countries have totally different standards. *Tu* is much more common in Québec, for example.

One last thing: remember that if your non-Frenchness is obvious from your accent, French people will normally forgive impertinent uses of *tu*, so don't stress out too much over this.

Edit: But Tipx's point is worth highlighting: **The consequences of using "tu" where you shouldn't are worse than the contrary.**

Comment: One more point he could have had to the list: * You can use "vous" in a context you would normally use "tu" in an humorous manner, and it's NOT disrespectful. However, you can use "tu" in a context where you should use "vous" in a manner to clearly express disrespect. A rule of thumb : The consequences of using "tu" where you shouldn't are worst than the contrary.

Comment: This is one of the best answers on the site.

Comment: The last point is very important.

Comment: Although culture is very important, the main effect is that the rules affect social relationships. Whatever my social relationship, the word I use is entirely dependent on the the language: in French I always use the rules in the answers below; in Irish I always use *tu* in the singular and *sibh* /ʃiv/ in the plural, but in the closely related Scots Gaelic, I use rules very similar to French, with *tu* (which usually changes to *thu* /u/) for French *tu* and *sibh* /ʃif/ for *vous*. So I would change, even mid-conversation, if I changed language. I quite often change between Irish and Gaelic.

Answer (score 13):

*Vous* is used when you are talking to a person in a formal situation (like your superior), or to a stranger.

*Tu* is used when talking to somebody you know well enough. It is often considered okay to say *tu* when persons address each other using their given name.

(To address several persons *vous* is always used.)

Answer (score 13):

## In France

### *Vous* use cases

You use *vous*:

- by default, when you don't know the person and the person is older,
- by default, when you don't know the person and the person has the same age and you are over 30 years old,
- as a mark of respect to someone (for example a father/mother in law),
- when you want to sound old-fashionly romantic (saying *vous* to a woman that you generally address with *tu* can have a certain charm when used properly, as a mark of a mix of respect, tenderness, shyness, and more),
- by default, when addressing a customer, or more generally someone you are in relation with through professional obligations (but not part of the same organization as you).

It is customary that the teacher, the boss, the parent in law, the elder, etc. proposes using *tu* the first.

### *Tu* use cases

You use *tu* :

- when you are well acquainted with the person,
- when addressing children / teenagers (some teachers might prefer to use *vous* with teenagers though, to build some distance and respect with the pupils),
- when you are well acquainted with the person, and not in a public situation where you have to show some distance with that person (well acquainted politicians and journalists use *tu* only off the record, for example),
- within left-wing political parties, the norm is to address one another with *tu* (the more to the left the stronger),
- when you want to sound young and cool (radio broadcast animated by people who target a young audience will systematically use *tu* when on the air).

### Remarks

Some people use only *tu*, no matter what.

In unclear situations, many people tend to avoid having to use the pronoun altogether until the issue is resolved.

Comment: > Some people use only "tu", no matter what.

I've never heard of this; any examples?

Comment: @Vincent : some people who are close to anarchist / libertarian movements, for instance. I used to know a bookshop owner who would systematically use "tu". It's not very common, but depending on the kind of social circles you roam into, you may find many of them.

Comment: I see, thanks for the info!

Comment: @Brennan, I've only ever met two people like that. Both would have been valid subject matter for a psychology thesis :)

Comment: The "tu" is also supposed to be _de rigueur_ between alumni of some specific schools, regardless of their respective age or situation. Theoretically, I could use it to address at least two former Prime Ministers of France.

Comment: @BrennanVincent Claude Sarraute is known to use "tu" no matter what.

Answer (score 7):

Vincent gives the main things to know.

On the other hand, I am a native and I don't like to be patronized, so since I am 20 I apply a strict reciprocity rule : if you use "tu" with me I will do the same (same for "vous"). Of course, if I use "tu" with someone, I won't be offended that he do the same with me ;)

Comment: I actually agree with you on this, but it's a matter of personal taste, highly controversial, and probably not something we should teach beginning learners :)

Comment: You're right. I gave a +1 to your comment.

Comment: Merci :) Moi, j'ai 22 ans et je fais comme toi, à une différence près: Je vouvoie les parents de mes amis français, même s'ils me tutoient, jusqu'à ce qu'ils me proposent de les tutoyer.

Answer (score 4):

There is a simple rule of thumb based on what you would call the person in question.
Ex: use "Tu" when you are on a first-name basis, and "vous" if on a last-name basis.

---

**Use "Vous" for people you address by**

- Last name     (Smith, Dupont)
- Title (Miss, Sir, Professor)
- Honorific (Your Honor)
- Profession (President)

**Use "Tu" for people you address by**

- First name (Abigail, Robert)
- Nickname (Abby, B-dog)
- Family title (Mom, Granpa)

---

There are many situations where not following this rule is *accepted*, but not *mandatory*.
Ex:    During middle and high school, teachers may address their students using various combinations like Lastname+Tu, Firstname+Vous, etc.

Comment: Note : I didn't know what to call "familly nicknames/titles", also it's a fairly old question but I think this rule of thumb is a bit simpler to remember and apply than most other answers.

Answer (score 3):

I tend to always hear "tu" in québec. And "vous" is used usually speaking formally to your boss.

Answer (score 3):

You must use *Vous* when talking to several persons.

Using *Vous* when talking to only one person marks the respect, including the simple and polite respect.

You can use *Tu* in relaxed mode, that is :

- When you talk to a young person (when they not seems adult yet, lets say about 18
  to 24). Note that you have to use *Vous* for hight titled young
  person, like a young prince)
- Very young kid that don't know to speak well can say *Tu* (lets say until about 4 or 6 years old).
- When you talk to people you are familiar with. That is your family, your friends, some of your neighbors, may be some closed colleagues at work, ... You can say *Tu* to God. Note that in some families of the hight society, child have to use *Vous* to their parents.
- When you talk in associative collaboration where it seems to be the usage (associations, Internet
  forums, even at work in some companies, ...)

Because of an [old usage coming from the French Revolution](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%C3%A9cret_sur_le_tutoiement_obligatoire) (when the French King was removed), some rare people are used to always say *Tu* to everybody. This may appear very strange, even to Frenches, but it's tolerated.

When people become to be familiar, or want to speak relaxed, they often propose to say *Tu* : "On peut se tutoyer".

Answer (score 2):

- When you are talking to many persons: always *vous*
- To your teacher: *vous*
- Teachers to students: often *tu*, sometimes *vous* but only for teenagers (and always *vous* in the university)
- To persons of your family: *tu*, even to old persons (you might see people using *vous* with their parents in the old books, but it is not used anymore)
- To children and teenagers (from an adult and among them): *tu*
- To people you don't know well: *vous*
- To your boss: *vous*, unless (s)he tells you to say *tu*

And there is a very important rule that is very useful for us French and even more for foreign people: when you don't know whether you have to use *tu* or *vous*, always say *vous*, because it is less embarrassing to respect a person too much than not enough.

Answer (score 2):

My advise would be that, when you don't know what to use, except for children (where tu is probably your best choice), would be to use vous by default as it is more respectful.

Then, at the beginning or later, if you want to be more friendly (so that's not with everyone, generally not with your boss for instance), you can ask "Est-ce que je peux te/vous tutoyer?" (which would mean "Can I use 'tu' when I speak with you?") or, if someone talking with you currently use "vous", you could tell him if you want it to use "tu", "Tu peux me tutoyer si tu veux" (You can use "tu" if you want).

Answer (score 1):

I use "tu" everytime, mostly because I don't know the "vous" version of the word. E.g. *tiens* or *tenez*.

It's pretty obvious that I'm a foreigner, even with putting on a decent Bergeracois accent. My skin tone must give it away.

I've never come across anybody taking "tu" in a disrespectful way, they'd be more disappointed with just speaking English at them. Due to the amount of tourists and ex-pats who don't speak anything but English. The Dordogne residents seem to be more than happy with informal talk than being shouted at in English.

Answer (score 0):

To summarize, *vous* is the formal version of *you*, an example of this is the sentence *Je Vous Aime*, yet the informal version of this sentence is *Je t'Aime*.

Comment: "Je tu aime" n'existe pas en français!

Comment: Merci, j'ai edite maintenant