# What are some tricks for avoiding the tu/vous dilemma?

Tags: usage, politesse

Following on from [this](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/213/vous-or-tu) question about using vous/tu, and specifically a throwaway remark by [subtenante](https://french.stackexchange.com/users/136/subtenante), what are some tricks that you can use to *avoid* having to use either, if you're uncertain?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There are several strategies.

- Change the whole focus of the sentence. For instance, you want to flatter the person by asking "did you cook this meal yourself?" (knowing that he/she did cook it indeed), you'd be tempted to ask *avez-vous cuisiné ce plat vous-même?* ; you'll have to ask *ce plat est délicieux, qui l'a cuisiné ?* instead.
- For "your", instead of *ton/votre*, always use *ce*. You want to borrow something, you won't ask it like "puis-je emprunter ton/votre ..." but either "puis-je emprunter ce ...".
- If talking to someone you know very well from an organisation, like a different company, but you're not sure of the context (formal/informal?) just always say *vous* and pretend you talk about the organisation as a whole, which is always a plural, if you get any remark.
- Sometimes, you just can't. In this case, use *vous* repeatedly until the person makes clear that the *tu* is ok. :)
- Some people have the dirty habit of using neither *vous* nor *tu* but will use a third-person instead. Typical from shop owners who want to sound a little fancy: *Et il lui faudra quoi au monsieur?* Do **not** do that.

Comment: using the third person can sound condescending

Comment: Marking as accepted because this is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Upvoted for the "do not do that" (et il lui faudra quoi au monsieur), that's so ugly

Answer (score 5):

Use this simple rule: use *vous* by default.

I often ask if I can use *tu* after a couple of sentences. The answer is always yes.

Comment: Probably the safest approach, but I would qualify it by a note on the importance of age difference: without going full-blown into the whole *vous vs. tu* debate, if you are within a couple years of each other, and both under 30-40, "tu" is probably a safe default...

Answer (score 5):

Use "tu" and say "My mother tongue is english, I don't do such difference" and smile

Comment: I though thou always used you.

Answer (score 2):

Another trick as I discovered by answering [another question](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/875) : sometimes, you can use *nous*:

- Ne nous énervons pas!
- Comment allons-nous ce matin?
- Prendons-nous du sucre avec notre café?

I'm not saying it's always applicable, and it will sound weird in a lot of cases, but it's worth knowing.

As [already mentionned](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/231), the third person can also be used, but probably only butlers can pull that one off:

- Monsieur a-t-il bien dormi?
- Madame est servie.

Comment: Alors, nous avons un problème avec l'ajout des liens? :)

Comment: Nous ne nous abaissons pas à relire notre réponse avant de la soumettre.

Comment: Ca, c'est une autre utilisation du nous ! On dit 'le nous royal' en français ?

Comment: Va voir l'autre question :-)

Comment: I would not recommend that a non-native speaker attempt *nous* or *monsieur* in the second person. It's a very uncommon turn of phrase; at best it is likely to be misunderstood, and if understood it will often be perceived as condescending. As the [TLF](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/nous) puts it (I.A.4.b): “exprimer certaines nuances de sentiment (sympathie, condescendance, reproche affectueux, parfois ironie)”.

Comment: That's not a good trick: if (and I say if :p) these examples would be acceptable, then in all these cases, the "vous" would have been better than this "nous" or "monsieur" and you should not even think to use "tu"...

Comment: Just to be clear, I'm not recommending or even advocating this, and certainly not for new speakers. But I feel it's worth mentionning. That said, I believe _Ne nous énervons pas_ isn't that bad.

Answer (score 1):

- Ne pas adresser la parole à la personne concernée
- Parler seulement de généralités en évitant de s'adresser directement à la personne
- Parler toujours au pluriel

Comment: * Ne pas parler?

Comment: on lui conseille aussi de regarder ses pieds