# Dois-je utiliser « on » ou « nous » ?

Tags: usage, pronoms, pronoms-personnels

Dans les situations où on doit utiliser « vous » à la place de « tu », doit-on aussi utiliser « nous » à la place de « on » ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ce sont des phénomènes séparés mais pas indépendants.

L'utilisation de *on* pour dire *nous* (ce qui ne recouvre pas tous les usages de *on*), c'est du langage courant, peu formel.

L'emploi de *vous* plutôt que *tu* est essentiellement une marque de respect.

Généralement on est plus formel face à des personnes qu'on vouvoie, mais ce n'est pas le seul contexte où on est formel et on peut adopter un langage plus familier même avec des personnes qu'on vouvoie (je vouvoie mon voisin, en partie à cause de la différence d'âge, mais je suis globalement moins formel avec lui qu'avec mon patron que je tutoie pourtant — mais je ne suis pas sûr que je sois si formel avec lui que j'évite *on* pour *nous*).

Answer (score 10):

Pour le remplacement de *nous* par *on*, voir aussi [la question correspondante](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/72/on-remplace-nous-quel-nom-pour-ce-processus), ou la [réponse de Slublu](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/873/).

Si la forme *nous* est en général utilisée pour la première personne du pluriel, elle peut également être utilisée pour une personne unique, on parle d'un pluriel *de majesté* (ou *majestatif* mais je ne retrouve pas ce mot dans le TLF):

> Nous, préfet de la Seine, ordonnons...

On peut également utiliser *nous* pour une deuxième (voire troisième) personne:

> Ne nous énervons pas! (pour *Ne t'énerve pas!* ou *Ne vous énervez pas!*)

Ce qui rejoint la question initiale, et on voit même que *nous* peut être une bonne manière [d'éluder la problématique *tu/vous*](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/228/what-are-some-tricks-for-avoiding-the-tu-vous-dilemma).

En bref, les différences entre ces formes sont plus subtiles qu'on [(ne)](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/138) pourrait le penser de prime abord et il nous serait préférable de lire en détail [l'entrée du TLF sur *nous*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/nous) qui explique tout ça bien mieux.

Comment: +1 pour la reference au "ne explétif" ;)

Comment: Faut pas m'encourager, de peur que ça [(ne)](http://french.stackexchange.com/q/138) me donne envie de recommencer...

Answer (score 1):

Non.  La phénomène de vouvoiement et tutoiement est une question distincte.  Quand on veut parler d'un groupe de personnes dont le parleur est un membre, on peut choisir d'utiliser les deux: "nous" ou "on".  Attention: "nous" se réfère toujours aux groupes dont le parleur est un membre; en revanche, "on" peut aussi vouloir dire "je", "personnes en général", ou même "vous".

Comment: Well, technically, _nous_ **can** mean _je_ or _vous_; and even "personnes in général" sometimes: _En Belgique, nous avons de belles vaches._ I don't own any cow myself, yet the usage of _nous_ is valid. (Granted, you could argue that I am still part of _nous_ in this case)

Answer (score 1):

Généralement, *on* est légèrement plus familier que *nous*, mais sans jamais être incorrect. Son emploi n'est pas réellement lié au tutoiement ou au vouvoiement.

Ainsi:

> Nous irons demain.
>  
>   Nous sommes prêts.
>   Sommes-nous invités à cette réunion ?

sont tout à fait appropriés dans les cas où un certain niveau de langage est requis, et où généralement l'on vouvoie. En famille, entre amis, cela peut sonner un peu formel ou sérieux, sans que ce ne soit à bannir pour autant, et bien que l'on y utilise le tutoiement.

Tandis que:

> On ira demain.
>   On est prêt.
>   Est-on invités à cette réunion ?

sont appropriés dans des cas moins formels, mais ne tombent pas dans le familier. J'emploie régulièrement ces tournures avec mes collègues, par exemple. Même avec ceux que je vouvoie. Je les emploie aussi en famille, parfois, alors que j'y utilise le tutoiement.

Enfin:

> On y va demain.
>   On est prêt.
>   On est invités à cette réunion ?

relèvent du langage familiers (la seconde est bien la même que plus haut : elle n'a pas que je sache de tournure plus familière). A moins de proches collègues, avec qui on se permet parfois quelques familiarités, ces tournures sont à réserver au cadre amical ou familial (sauf la seconde évidemment, puisque c'est la même que plus haut).

Comment: De même que "on est invités" s'accorde au pluriel, j'accorderais "on est prêts" au pluriel, non ?

Comment: Ah, effectivement. Je l'ai probablement écrit de cette façon car je pensais à "nous" en tant que "groupe uni" donc en tant qu'unité.

Comment: C'est plus que "légèrement" informel, mais sur le reste, je suis d'accord.

Comment: @Quidam - Aïe! La vraie langue française se "perd", elle ne se "perds" pas! Autrement je suis d'accord avec le fond, on y perd au change. Aussi, "beaucoup" utilisé seul est normalement au pluriel, donc, beaucoup l'utilisent...

Answer (score -3):

Le 《on》 est utilisé pour une généralité, qui ne désigne pas quelqu'un de particulier. Aujourd'hui beaucoup l'utilise couramment, par exemple: 《on va se promener.》 C'est une faute de français, on devrait dire 《Nous allons nous promener.》 Malheureusement,la langue française (la vraie) se perds et pour les gens utiliser le pronom 《nous》 est devenu du langage soutenu alors que ce n'est pas le cas, ça s'appelle bien parler.
Normalement: Je, tu, il/elle, nous, vous, ils/elles.
Pour beaucoup de gens: Je, tu, il/elle, on, vous, ils/elles...

Comment: "Malheureusement,la langue française (la vraie) se perds" Visiblement, elle se perd plus vite chez ceux qui s'en plaignent le plus.

Comment: Ah bon? Vous pourriez dire quand on a commencé à utiliser le "on" pour un "nous"? ça date de votre naissance? Et aussi, j'aimerais des références qui montrent que c'est "une faute de français".