# Le tutoiement et le vouvoiement au Québec

Tags: vouvoiement, québec, tutoiement

Cette question se veut la version québécoise d'[une autre](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/213/how-do-you-decide-whether-to-use-vous-or-tu) qui a déjà été posée. En effet, je voudrais qu'on décrive dans quel(s) contexte(s) on vouvoie et on tutoie au Québec.

J'ai pu remarquer que c'est très différent par rapport hier soir: j'ai appelé à une auberge de jeunesse à Montréal pour avoir des renseignements, et l'homme qui a répondu au téléphone, bien que complètement inconnu, m'a tutoyé :

> Ben, t'as le temps, là ; si tu vas venir au mois de janvier, c'est pas la peine de faire ta réservation avant le mois de décembre !

Je ne suis pas sûr, mais je pense que la quasi-totalité des Français m'auraient vouvoyé à sa place.

Alors, expliquez-moi le vouvoiement et le tutoyement au Québec !

Comment: Merci pour l'edit @F'x ; ça n'avait pas de sens sinon :)

Comment: A chaque fois que je vais au QC, je m'arrange à tourner mes phrases pour que mon interlocuteur ait à faire le choix avant moi et je tutoie/vouvoie en conséquence ;-)

Comment: Je suis curieux d'entendre la réponse: je n'ai jamais entendu un vouvoiement au Québec (et j'ai toujours considéré que le vouvoiement était rarissime là bas).

Answer (score 8):

Au Québec, peu de gens seront vexés de se faire tutoyer. Le vouvoiement est plutôt utilisé dans un contexte très très formel comme une entrevue, lorsqu'on rencontre un supérieur pour la première fois, dans une communication avec un client, etc. Même dans un contexte académique, on tutoie assez rapidement un professeur. Si tu as besoin d'information d'un étranger, on peut aussi le tutoyer, par exemple je l'aborderais ainsi: "Excuse-moi, est-ce que tu sais où je pourrais trouver...".

Bref, en général, dans une situation comme la tienne, le vouvoiement aurait été le plus approprié mais il peut arriver que le tutoiement soit quand même utilisé.

Comment: A noter aussi que manifestement les Québecois utilisent plus facilement _tu_ pour _on_.

Comment: Bonne réponse, mais comment osez-vous me tutoyer ?! Just kidding :)

Comment: VoidStar: Vous ne pouvez pas dire que « personne ne sera vexer » car vous ne connaissez par toutes les personnes. Pour donner un exemple, mon ex beau-père répond « On a pas élever les cochons ensembles » lorsqu'il se faisait tutoyer, alors je considère que c'est être vexé. @Joubarc : Je considère ton commentaire comme une réponse en soit. Je te suggère de l'ajouter comme une réponse car pour bien comprendre l'usage québécois, il faut connaitre cet élément.

Answer (score 5):

Personnellement, je crois que le contexte d'une auberge de jeunesse, ou probablement une personne d'un âge relativement jeune, avec un contexte social assez amical justifierait ton expérience.

Je crois qu'à un certain âge (20-30 ans) il y a plusieurs Québécois qui utilisent un tutoiement poli. Sans être nécessairement lié à votre expérience, je crois que pour une partie de la population québécoise, le vouvoiement a peut-être été lié à une classe plus riche ou hautaine. Pour se rapprocher les uns des autres, un tutoiement a peut-être été adopté par certains.

Ça reste mon humble opinion et point de vue de Québécois.

Comment: Philippe, je posais une question sur ton usage de « plusieurs » http://french.stackexchange.com/q/713/176, et il se fait que @Joubarc et moi avons compris le « à un certain age » de façon totalement opposée.  Quel est le sens que tu voulais donner ?

Comment: « à un certain age » visait ici une précision dans la strate d'age et non « à un age important, vieux ».

Comment: Mon utilisation de « plusieurs » était purement instinctif et naturelle pour moi. À savoir si c'est le meilleur mot, je ne sais pas. Selon moi, certain = 20%, plusieurs = -50%, beaucoup = +50%. Mais c'est ma simple perception personnelle.

Answer (score 2):

En plus de ce que @Joubarc mentionne concernant le fait que le « tu » soit souvent utilisé pour substituer le « on », j'ajouterai l'élément suivant : Le niveau d'implication, ou l'émotion, de la personne s'exprimant peut pousser l'interlocuteur à tutoyer plutôt qu'à vouvoyer. Je pense que cela vient d'un sentiment de proximité avec l'autre personne.

Dans le cas présent, d'après le « **Ben,** t'as le temps **, là** », et le point d'exclamation à la fin de la phrase, la personne au téléphone semble trouver cela plus qu'évident qu'il ne faille réserver qu'un mois à l'avance, au point de trouver cela amusant.

Answer (score 1):

Bonjour mon nom est Marc Lavoie.
Voici mon opinion sur le vouvoiement. Nous avons été entre nous depuis 400 ans. Entre nous c'est aussi que tout le monde est égal. Apres les têtes tranchées en France, la France d'en haut subsista jusqu’à nos jours. Tandis qu'au Québec il n'a jamais été question de monarchie et la Reine d'Angleterre était bien loin. Nous nous sommes donc tutoyé. Bien sur que Monsieur le notaire , le docteur méritait un vous mais fallait qu'il nous fasses... m

Comment: Pour aller plus loin et éviter les opinions dans les réponses, je suggère des citations qui réfléchissent la recherche.  Bienvenue sur French SE ; voici le [tour].

Answer (score 1):

Il y a [peu de différences](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/218/26366) régionales en ce qui a trait aux contextes où l'on vouvoie (« personnes qu’on rencontre pour la première fois, ses supérieurs hiérarchiques, les personnes plus âgées que soi. Dans certains cas, une personne peut tutoyer, tandis que son interlocuteur emploie le vous », [BDL](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=5140)) et ceux où l'on tutoie (« les adolescents et les jeunes adultes se tutoient spontanément, tout comme généralement les membres d’une même famille. Le tutoiement spontané est aussi d’usage dans des milieux de travail, des clubs, des associations », [BDL](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=5140)).

Cependant, le tutoiement spontané à la première rencontre est plus fréquent au Québec et c'est vraiment ça la différence à mon avis :

> Dans certaines aires francophones, au Québec notamment, dire *tu* dès la
> première rencontre est beaucoup plus fréquent que dans d’autres, où le
> tutoiement spontané peut être ressenti comme une familiarité déplacée.
> Il faut être sensible à cet état de fait. (*Banque de dépannage linguistique*, « [Vouvoiement et tutoiement](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=5140) »)

Quant à l'anecdotique, la conscience de ce qui précède explique peut-être qu'une médecin d'origine française m'ait tutoyé (comme patient). C'est peut-être que quand je vouvoie des gens, il arrive parfois que je dise *tu* quand j'explique une chose (« ...c'est comme si tu avais une douleur dans le dos etc. », alors que dans le reste du discours je les vouvoie.). J'aime aussi beaucoup le vouvoiement avec le prénom en contexte formel pour ajouter une petite touche de collégialité (mais le prénom doit être rapidement suivi du verbe à la deuxième personne du pluriel) : « Suzanne, voulez-vous un café ? ».

Comment: « Dans des contextes protocolaires très officiels, il est conseillé d’attendre la quatrième rencontre avant de penser se tutoyer. » (BDL). Puis après y avoir pensé pendant quelques jours, on pourra procéder ;-)