# « Plusieurs » et « certains » (ou dois-je dire « plusieurs » ?) au Québec

Tags: adjectifs, régionalismes, québec

Dans une [réponse récente](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/692/le-tutoiement-et-le-vouvoiement-au-quebec/712#712), on trouve :

> Je crois qu'à un certain âge (20-30 ans) il y a plusieurs Québécois qui utilisent un tutoiement poli.

Ce n'est pas la première fois que je rencontre cette utilisation par des Québécois de « plusieurs » dans un contexte où j'aurais utilisé « certains » (ici « Jusqu'à un age de 20-30 ans, certains Québécois utilisent un tutoiement poli. », je suis aussi un peu surpris par le début de la phrase, mais ce n'est pas l'objet de ma question).  Il ne me semble pas que j'ai jamais remarqué cet usage chez d'autres personnes.

Est-ce que cet usage existe ailleurs ?  Est-ce qu'il y a une nuance que je ne perçois pas ?

Comment: Pour le début de phrase (qui n'est donc pas l'objet de la question), j'aurais tendance à l'interpréter comme _à partir d'un certain âge_ ou _arrivé à un certain âge_ plutôt que comme _jusqu'à un certain âge_. Et pour le remplacement de _certains_ par _plusieurs_ de la fin de phrase... jamais entendu en Belgique.

Comment: @Joubarc, je comprends ta position, mais je conçois mal le tutoiement à partir d'un certain age et très bien jusqu'à un certain age.

Comment: Oui, je répondais hors-contexte, mais c'est vrai que dans la phrase originale ça n'aurait pas beaucoup de sens. Mais je pense quand même qu'il n'y a pas de notion de _jusqu'à_; plutôt, on vise les jeunes de 20 à 30 ans. Même si les jeunes en-dessous de 20 tutoiement certainement aussi, l'emphase est mise sur les 20-30 ans qui, eux, devraient vouvoyer. Enfin, c'est vrai que c'est un peu bizarre comme tournure.

Comment: @Montéedelait La réponse de *personne* ammene l'origine Quebecoise, mais en Europe le sens ce fait modifier par l'Académie Française dans la 5e edition. Le plus drole est que la préface de la cinquieme édition est écrite avec le mot 'plusieurs' écrit dans un contexte de beaucoups. *Durant **plusieurs** années, tout ce qui n’est pas entré dans la Révolution comme instrument et comme acteur, a été regardé et traité comme contre-révolutionnaire.*

Comment: @yagmoth555 Je ne crois pas que la définition de la 5e édition exclut entièrement la signification *beaucoup*. Elle se contente de modifier sa définition et d'y introduire la possibilité que sa valeur puisse être modeste *(Un nombre plus ou moins considérable, faisant partie d'un autre nombre plus grand)*. Cette possibilité, ayant apparemment fait boule de neige en Europe, n'aurait peut-être simplement pas marqué autant le parler québécois. Par ailleurs, la citation de la question est clairement indiquée comme émanant d'un Québécois. La réponse que je prime la met clairement dans ce contexte.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

La différence est dans le nombre. Je perçois généralement plusieurs comme étant plus grand que certains. Dans cet exemple, j'ai l'impression que plusieurs implique une majorité connaissant personnellement cette quantité.

Answer (score 6):

Mon avis (et je suis Français) :

- « certains », ça englobe une quantité indéterminée de personnes (que l'on aura généralement tendance à supposer faible¹) qui répondent le plus souvent à un ou différents critères particuliers.
- « plusieurs » qui  est d'habitude limité à une petite poignée, serait ici un euphémisme qui veut dire « beaucoup »².

—

<sup>1. Mais le contraire peut être précisé (cf. commentaires).

2. Ou presque. En tout cas, plus que « quelques » ; et j'aurais bien évité la confusion, mais peut-être que « un certain nombre » s'en rapproche aussi.</sup>

Comment: « Certains » n'a pas pour moi d'implication sur le nombre, juste que ce n'est pas tous. « Certains, et ils sont nombreux, pensent que ... » me semble correct par exemple.

Comment: Et donc, *plusieurs Québecois*, ça peut être combien ? Pour moi (France), et si j'ai bien compris pour [Shlublu](http://french.stackexchange.com/q/719#719) (France) et [Joubarc](http://french.stackexchange.com/q/717#717) (Belgique), ça peut être 8 Québecois mais pas 8000 Québecois (ce qui ne serait pourtant que 1‰ de la population, et pourrait se dire *quelques Québecois* (impliquant une faible proportion) ou *certains Québecois* (sans forte connotation de taille)).

Comment: @Gilles. Bah, c'est très variable, je peux te poser la même question avec « beaucoup ». Pas facile de répondre. En général c'est subjectif, et ça veut souvent dire « plus que ce que les gens pensent » (avec des niveaux d'insistance divers). Je dirais que là ça exprime un nombre non négligeable qui s'exprime en pourcentage et pas en unités (mais ce n'est que *mon* interprétation dans *ce* contexte). L'astuce c'est aussi de se mettre à l'abri grâce à ce genre d'expression… on se mouille pas trop en disant « plusieurs ». Bien sûr, faudrait aussi demander aux Québecois ce que eux en pensent :-)

Comment: « Certains » est pour moi indéterminé (c'est une partie des Québécois, mais laquelle?), « plusieurs » est plus déterminé. J'aurais pu écrire « plusieurs Québécois ont utilisé _plusieurs_ dans un contexte où je ne l'aurais pas fait » (j'ai les noms de ceux auxquels je pense ici, il y en a peut-être, d'autres mais c'est pas d'eux dont il s'agit).  Si j'écris « certains Québécois ... » c'est plus vague et je parle aussi des Québécois qui ont utilisé ce tour sans que je le remarque.

Answer (score 5):

[La définition **B**](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/plusieurs) du **pronom** *plusieurs* peut être utilisée d'une manière similaire. La phrase d'origine deviendrait alors:

> Au Québec, plusieurs utilisent un tutoiement poli.

Si en Europe cette signification est à priori moins utilisée, peut-être est-ce le contraire au Québec où elle a en plus migré du pronom vers l'adjectif.

Sinon, je rejoins Stéphane, en Belgique aussi, *plusieurs* est utilisé comme euphémisme comme quantité entre *quelques-uns* et *beaucoup*:

> Jules: Je n'ai jamais vu de banque dans le coin, tu sais où il y en a une?
>   Arnaud: Ho ben , y'en a plusieurs, pourtant.

Comment: Pour moi, en France, *plusieurs* ne conviendrait pas ici. Pour un petit ensemble de personnes concernées, *plusieurs* est plus grand que *quelques-uns*, mais *quelques-uns* est relatif (*quelques Québecois*, c'est peut-être 5% des Québecois) alors que *plusieurs* est absolu (*plusieurs Québecois*, c'est peut-être 5 Québecois). Les exemples du sens B du TLF marchent pour moi, mais ont une valeur absolue (*plusieurs* = au moins 3, sans la connotation de faible nombre qu'a *quelques*). Est-ce qu'en Belgique, on pourrait utiliser *plusieurs* ici ?

Comment: Où ça ici? Tu veux dire, dans _Il y a plusieurs Québecois qui utilisent un tutoiement poli_? Non, pas tellement, mais j'ai du mal à définir la limite. Par exemple, _À Bruxelles, il y a plusieurs librairies_ ne me pose pas de problème, tandis que _En France, il y a plusieurs germanophones_ me choque. Je dirais comme toi que _plusieurs_ ne peut pas adéquatement exprimer un trop grand nombre. Et je vois ce que tu veux dire avec la notion d'absolu - c'est vrai que la notion de _plusieurs_ me donne aussi parfois l'impression qu'on pourrait les citer tous, mais pas systématiquement.

Comment: « Certains » à un sens fort de « une partie », donc « certaines librairies » va pour moi être complété par une proposition qui ne concernent pas toutes les librairies (dans un univers implicites ou explicites, « certaines librairies parisiennes ... »).

Comment: @Gilles, Je n'utiliserais pas « Au Québec, plusieurs utilisent un tutoiement poli. » mais je pourrais dire « J'ai rencontré plusieurs Québécois qui utilisent un tutoiement poli. »

Answer (score 5):

Je n'ai jamais rencontré cet usage en France. On dira plutôt :

> [Je crois qu'] à un certain âge (20-30 ans) certains Québécois utilisent le tutoiement poli.

Donc quelque chose de proche de  ce qui est suggéré dans cette question.

- On utilise « *plusieurs* », mais plutôt pour dénombrer. Pas pour indiquer l'existence de quelque chose sans le dénombrer.
- Le « *Je crois* » initial ne « sonne pas familier » à mon oreille, pourtant je ne peux pas dire qu'il ne pourrait être utilisé.
- Nous aurions tendance à ne pas employer *il y a … qui*, mais une forme plus directe.
- Nous aurions tendance à parler « du tutoiement » plutôt que « d'un tutoiement ».

Comment: Quand on parle d’un tutoiement poli, on indique qu’il s’agit d’une variété de tutoiement qui peut être perçue comme polie, à opposer à un tutoiement moins respectueux. Ce qui fera la différence entre les deux formes se situe à l’extérieur du tutoiement, dans le ton général, le choix du vocabulaire, la qualité de l’élocution, mais il y a malgré tout établissement d’une certaine biodiversité dans la classification des tutoiements. C'est ce que l'on indique avec *un* plutôt que *le*, qui maintiendrait l'unicité absolue du tutoiement.

Answer (score 4):

Il n'y a pas d'euphémisme ici. C'est un usage possiblement plus ancien qui est tombé en désuétude ailleurs, ça signifie *beaucoup, un grand nombre de* :

> [...] au Québec, *plusieurs* est aussi employé avec le sens de «
>   beaucoup, un grand nombre de ». Ce sens particulier s’ajoute donc au
>   sens de « un certain nombre », généralisé dans la francophonie.
>
> [...] Il est intéressant de noter que cet emploi de *plusieurs* avec le
>   sens de « beaucoup » est ancien. Ainsi, on peut lire dans la première
>   édition du [Dictionnaire](https://artflsrv03.uchicago.edu/philologic4/publicdicos/navigate/4/3564/) de l’Académie française, publiée en 1694,
>   que *plusieurs* signifie « beaucoup, quantité, grand nombre de ». Ce
>   n’est que dans la 5<sup>e</sup> édition de son [dictionnaire](https://artflsrv03.uchicago.edu/philologic4/publicdicos/navigate/11/6808/), en
>   1798, que l’Académie française donnera à *plusieurs* un sens
>   différent. On peut donc penser que les francophones du Québec ont
>   préservé un emploi qui a été peu à peu délaissé en Europe.
>
> [ Banque de dépannage linguistique (OQLF), « [plusieurs](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=2886) » ]

Donc c'est la différence entre *plus de deux mais généralement pas beaucoup de* et *beaucoup de*. À mon avis au Québec, *plusieurs* signifie généralement *beaucoup, un grand nombre de* à moins que le contexte n'indique autrement. Ici on entend *beaucoup de Québécois*.

Comment: Merci d'avoir apporté une réponse québécoise de circonstance à cette question. Le glissement de sens en Europe pourrait-il être survenu avec l'idée que plusieurs exclut la totalité, laquelle est parfois connue est de petite quantité? «Il a perdu plusieurs orteils après ces trois nuits d'enfer trappé au sommet du mont Logan» → on s'attend à au moins trois orteils, certes, mais vraisemblablement à moins de sept ou huit, auquel cas on penserait probablement à «presque tous ses orteils». — «Nous avons rencontré plusieurs des jumelles Dionne» → probablement trois...

Comment: @Montéedelait Bienvenue et merci beaucoup pour la récompense ! Pour la question du « glissement » en Europe je ne sais pas mais oui le contexte en effet. L'idée d'ensemble (doigts, jumelles etc.) et d'individualité ou d'unité fait en sorte qu'on a peut-être un emploi différent dans ces cas-là qui sont peut-être les cas usuels dans la vie de tous les jours finalement alors qu'avec _beaucoup_ c'est toujours beaucoup. Dans tous les cas la réponse (qui aurait pu être plus nuancée) était requise pour sortir les contributeurs du bourbier ici. Merci encore !

Comment: La promotion n’aura pas fait remonter beaucoup votre réponse, mais le petit symbole bleu du montant de la récompense, pleinement méritée, y sera désormais attaché. Souhaitons qu’il saura attirer l’attention des futurs lecteurs de cette question.

Answer (score 2):

En tant que français, tout aussi surpris par l'expression, je dirais que (en français métropolitain¹), *plusieurs* désigne un nombre de personnes qu'on compte, typiquement de 2 à 10 (et ça peut représenter beaucoup ou pas dépendamment de la taille du groupe englobant), alors que *certains* va souvent désigner une **proportion** d'individus dans le groupe (rarement très importante au demeurant).

D'où le fait que parmi la population québecoise, je dirais plus facilement *certains* pour une petite proportion, et *une majorité de*, ou *beaucoup de* pour une plus grande, mais que *plusieurs* me fait plutôt penser à seulement une poignée d'individus, donc me surprend (alors que par exemple, *quelques-uns* dirait la même chose en ayant l'air de dire *pas beaucoup*, contrairement *plusieurs* qui n'a pas cet air là).

Comme [l'indiquent](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/714/1514) [les autres](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/717/1514), *plusieurs* comme euphémisme, au Québec et ailleurs, semble une bonne explication du phénomène, en l'occurence.

<sub>1. Si j'écris *standard*, combien râlent ?</sub>

Comment: Combien râlent ? Si tu veux mon avis : plusieurs.