# How to decide between "vous" and "toi" in greetings ?

Tags: salutations, vouvoiement

I was curious about how to decide between using *"vous"* and *"toi"* in greetings.

I learned after  using:

> comment allez-vous

And I reply

> Je vais bien

Then, How to know whether to use *"Et toi?"*, or *"Et vous ?"*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En règle générale et sans tenir compte des variantes selon les époques et les pays, de nos jours, "toi" est réservé aux amis, aux personnes que nous connaissons bien, aux personnes de la même famille et aux enfants. "Vous" est la formule de politesse réservée aux personnes que nous ne connaissons pas. Après un certain temps, on peut décider de passer du vouvoiement au tutoiement. "Toi" exprime la familiarité, "vous" le respect et une certaine distance.

Comment: Voir les [réponses](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/213/how-do-you-decide-whether-to-use-vous-or-tu-comment-choisir-entre-vous) très détaillées déjà données à cette question.