# Does the tu/vous distinction more accurately express politeness, or social distance?

Tags: choix-de-mot, usage, histoire, politesse

The distinction between *tu* and *vous* fascinates me, perhaps because we don't have such a feature in English anymore. While it takes a few seconds of conscious thought for a learner like me to decide between the two in French interactions, the French do it intuitively.

One thing I've noticed is that especially in French television, *vous* seems to be used often in business situations like when interacting with people on the job, and rarely if ever with friends or family, which would seem to imply it's more formal and polite. But interestingly, **two people in a fight might switch to using *vous* where they would otherwise use *tu***. At least in American fights, you don't tend to increase your politeness toward your opponent :)

It would seem then that perhaps the concept encapsulated by the French *tu*/*vous* distinction isn't quite politeness, but rather social distance, using *tu* to pull someone close and *vous* to hold someone away. Is there any merit to this theory?

Comment: If we take deference/respect as a factor related to politeness, another example comes to mind: addressing God in the Judeo-Christian tradition. In theory that would be the situation *par excellence* where you'd have to be conscious of talking upwards in the hierarchy, but you use *tu*...

Comment: What do you mean by "two people in a fight might switch to using vous"?

Comment: There is a humorous, but actually very correct flowchart that explains when to use "tu" or "vous", you will see it reflects indeed a mixture of politeness and social distance: http://www.konbini.com/fr/tendances-2/expliquer-vouvoiement-anglophone/

Comment: @LukeSawczak: note that in several traditional prayers, the "vous" is used: "Notre père qui êtes aux cieux, que votre nom soit sanctifié, etc". I am not an expert in theological matters, but I believe the "tu" used to address God is rather recent (maybe a consequence of the Vatican II reforms in the 1960's) ?

Comment: Of course, in English you have to make similar decisions. Do you use someone’s first name to address them? Do you use ‘Sir’?

Comment: @Greg Neat; I don't know those prayers! Wikipedia [agrees](http://ow.ly/qvlz30gr5RM) with your timeline for them. That said, I suspect that the *vous* in them is the excrescence. Looking at e.g. the prayer in Matt. 6:9-13 I see it [has always used *tu*](https://oratoiredulouvre.fr/prier/Le-Notre-Pere.php) (incl. old translations such as Étaples, Martin, Ostervald, & Segond). Of course, those were based on the Vulgate which uses *nomen tuum*, and besides Jerome predates widespread Latin T-V. Koine Greek had no T-V either. So I wonder if that *vous* was just a temporary part of Church tradition.

Comment: @Greg Love the flowchart; I think I'll try it out with my students :)

Comment: @LukeSawczak: I see you are from Canada, pay attention that this flowchart applies very much to "European French". In Canadian French, the use of "tu" is much more widespread (eg, in French Canadian shops, the staff may address customers as "tu", whereas in Europe, this would be a no-no).

Comment: @Greg That's so useful!!

Answer (score 12):

Yes, I agree that *tu* or *vous* are not marks of politeness but marks of social distance / deference.

That's the reason why French people, regardless of whether they are polite or not, usually do not have to guess what to use. They know if the person in front of them is close enough or not and they remember if using *tu* was agreed in case the *vouvoiement* would have been the default usage.

What might confuse English people is when they are told using *tu* to someone you should have say *vous* is impolite, and using *vous* to someone you should have say *tu* is excessively polite.

They shouldn't worry that much. This *tu/vous* ruleset is very relaxed when applying to non native speakers learning French. We are very lenient in that case just like we do not care about young children who say *tu* to everyone. They simply haven't already learn to use the singular *vous*.

Switching from *vous* to *tu* is done either never or once, commonly after an invitation to do so from one of the parties.

Switching from *tu* to *vous* is extremely rare. Once you start saying *tu* to someone who doesn't express disagreement, there is no reason to revert.

Your fight example is a case where this can happen but it is still a very uncommon kind of event. The switch is indeed done to put some distance again between the people involved.

Another case is people talking together at the TV or radio who switch to *vous* for consistency and deference. For example a journalist that say *tu* in private to an interviewee and *vous* with some others will use *vous* with all of them in public.

See also [How do you decide whether to use "vous" or "tu"? / Comment choisir entre « vous » et « tu » ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/213/how-do-you-decide-whether-to-use-vous-or-tu-comment-choisir-entre-vous)

Comment: A personal example I can think of: someone in my family uses "vous" to address his wife when they quarrel (in front of the whole family...). Ex: "Mais que faites-vous ? Tout le monde vous attend !". As if he wanted to put some distance with her when he is mad at her. But it is so peculiar that the other family members make fun of his use of "vous", which shows it really stands out.

Answer (score 7):

Indeed the use of *tu/vous* is a matter of social distance. A misuse of *tu/vous* becomes a matter of politeness because the appropriate social distance has not been observed.

There are many ways you can observe social distance in the choice between *tu* and *vous*. For example:

- There are a number of formal situations where people stick to *vous* even if they would have otherwise used *tu* with the same person. For example: in the army, in Parliament, in judiciary hearings, ...
- Within a family, there is no social distance, so *tu* is the norm.
- The higher the social class, the more people use *vous* (even within the same class). Aristocratic and even bourgeois families used to use *vous*, but this is no longer practiced (or only by a select very few).
- During the Revolution, people started to use *tu* systematically, as a political statement: there are no social classes, so there should not be any marker of social distance between people.
- If two people meet in a dissymmetric situation such as a vendor and a customer, they will usually use *vous*. (Younger people might not, though.) The dissymmetry in the situation creates the need for social distance. If the same people later met again through mutual friends, they would use *tu*. At work, it depends on the company culture and the industry.
- People who see themselves as members of the same group tend to use *tu*. This applies not only to groups of friends, but also to social groups. People who attended the same school, who are active in the same political organization (at least left-leaning ones) or charity, or even who are members of the same sports club, often use *tu*, even though they would have used *vous* if they'd just met on the street.

Changing between *tu* and *vous* in a fight can go both ways. Changing to *vous* from the habitual *tu* can be a way to create some distance with the other person. Conversely, changing to *tu* from the habitual *vous* can be a way to breach the distance in order to stress the aggression.

Note that although French people choose intuitively, there are ambiguous cases where people don't know which one to choose. It's usually better to use *vous* when in doubt, because putting too little distance is worse than putting too much distance. However unduly using *vous* can also alienate people by putting too much distance. If you have a foreign accent, you'll generally be excused. Natives will usually ask when in doubt.