# In an Informal Setting How Long Do People Usually Wait to Use "Tu"

Tags: france, culture

So if you meet someone of the opposite gender (that you are romantically interested in) at a bar in France, how long do people usually wait to start using "tu"? An hour? later that evening? if they hang out again? weeks later?

Comment: Between 0 and ∞, but hopefully closer to 0 ;-) See also  https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/213/how-do-you-decide-whether-to-use-vous-or-tu-comment-choisir-entre-vous

Comment: @jlliagre Ah, I believe that the rule of "around 25 years old and of the same age" would likely cause the use of "tu". Possibly much older bar attendees would use vous!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Non locuteur natif du français (et étant marié depuis pas mal de temps je ne suis pas la personne la plus pertinente pour parler du flirt et comment flirter:-)!) mais selon ce site : [http://homerite.fr/odh/faut-il-tutoyer-ou-vouvoyer-sa-cible/#:~:text=On%20ne%20sait%20pas%20si,Sauf%20dans%20quelques%20situations](http://homerite.fr/odh/faut-il-tutoyer-ou-vouvoyer-sa-cible/#:%7E:text=On%20ne%20sait%20pas%20si,Sauf%20dans%20quelques%20situations).

**on commence toujours par tutoyer** (avec des exceptions...)!

> Lorsque vous abordez une femme sur internet, en général vous
> n’utilisez pas le vouvoiement c’est donc que vous saviez déjà que
> c’était mieux de tutoyer! Ou sinon c’est que vous faites partie de ces
> mecs, qui derrière leur ordinateur se permettent des choses et en face
> se déballonnent… Par contre, si même sur internet vous commenciez avec
> du « vous », il est temps d’arrêter ça immédiatement et c’est peut
> être pour ça que vos discussions ne débouchaient pas sur des
> rencontres…
>
> En soirée on tutoie, dans la rue on tutoie, si c’est l’amie d’une amie
> on tutoie, si elle est plus âgée que vous et que c’est une cible on
> tutoie aussi! Elle doit comprendre que vous n’avez pas froid aux yeux
> et que vous êtes à même de prendre des initiatives. Dans le cas
> contraire et si ce n’est pas une cible, vouvoyez comme le veut la
> coutume. N’allez pas dire « ouais mais Pierre t’avais dit qu’il faut
> tutoyer tout le monde sur ton blog »! Vous tutoyez car vous voulez
> être intime avec votre cible, mais si c’est pas le cas, utilisez le
> vouvoiement.

(...)

> Dans cette conclusion, je vais répondre à la seule question sans réponse de cet article : « peut-on séduire une femme en la vouvoyant »? Bien sûr que c’est possible. Car ça ne vous empêchera pas d’actionner certains mécanismes de séduction. Mais quand vous rencontrez quelqu’un, le vouvoiement dresse une barrière entre vous et votre cible car depuis que vous êtes enfant on vous a appris à vouvoyer les grandes personnes. Toutes vos relations avec ces personnes ont été distantes, et symbolisées par le vouvoiement. Donc si vous avez envie d’être plus proches de votre cible : tutoyez! Car c’est ce que vous avez toujours fait avec les gens qui vous sont proches. Tutoyer n’est pas un manque de respect, c’est juste une tentative de connexion privée.

Une enquête révèle que même parmi les locuteurs natifs il n'y a pas un consensus véritable. Personnellement, je crois que la réponse est vraiment substantive.

https://forum.doctissimo.fr/psychologie/celibat/vouvoiement-rapport-seduction-sujet_208155_1.htm

http://www.jeuxvideo.com/forums/1-51-15794580-1-0-1-0-tutoyer-ou-vouvoyer-pour-draguer.htm

https://www.seduireunhomme.fr/forum/viewtopic.php?id=1731

**EDIT**

J'ajoute aussi la nuance apportée par un locuteur natif (merci @Greg) :

> Je ne suis plus dans le "game" depuis des années, mais je pense qu'il
> faut aussi "sentir" le type de bar. Si c'est un bar à la clientèle
> jeune, avec de la musique forte, clairement propice aux rencontres, le
> "tu" est naturel. Par contre, imaginons un bar d'hôtel par exemple, si
> on y aborde quelqu'un, le "vous" est indiqué, le "tu" serait vraiment
> impoli.

Voir aussi :

[Est-ce qu'on se tutoie?](https://french.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37/est-ce-quon-se-tutoie)

[How do you decide whether to use "vous" or "tu"? / Comment choisir entre « vous » et « tu » ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/213/how-do-you-decide-whether-to-use-vous-or-tu-comment-choisir-entre-vous)

(merci @jlliagre)

Comment: Ah merci! A Paris, quand j'ai rencontré une fille française au bar, je ne savais pas parler français. Elle m'a dit des phrases en français à utiliser en ville, mais a fait remarquer que pour elle et moi "tu". Nous allions nous rencontrer cet été mais le virus ... et je me demandais si c'était rapide pour elle de faire ça. Avec les réponses, je pense que c'était normal. Désolé si mon français est encore mauvais!

Comment: Je ne suis plus dans le "game" depuis des années, mais je pense qu'il faut aussi "sentir" le type de bar. Si c'est un bar à la clientèle jeune, avec de la musique forte, clairement propice aux rencontres, le "tu" est naturel. Par contre, imaginons un bar d'hôtel par exemple, si on y aborde quelqu'un, le "vous" est indiqué, le "tu" serait vraiment impoli.